# A vector of Mat images is changed after being transferred to a class

Tags: class, opencv, dll, vector

I have a strange problem that causes missing variables after a communication between a class in a dll and the main app. The main app is loading 8 Mat images into a vector then calling a library dll to process it.

Here is the main app codes:

```
int ReturnCode = 0;

HINSTANCE DLLCALL = LoadLibrary(L"IMAGEPROC.dll");


Interface_factory factoryFunc = reinterpret_cast<Interface_factory>(::GetProcAddress(DLLCALL, "CreateCOGInterfaceObject"));

if (!factoryFunc) {
    ReturnCode = ERROR_UNABLETOLOADLIBRARY;

    ::FreeLibrary(DLLCALL);

    return ReturnCode;
}

COGInterface* cog = factoryFunc();


ReturnCode = Commitment(argc, argv, cog);


FreeLibrary(DLLCALL);

return ReturnCode;
```

In the Commitment:

```
vector<Mat>vectorImages;    
for (int i = 0; i < NumFiles; i++) {
        string FileTemp = "";
        FileTemp.append(LastFileStatus);
        FileTemp.append(to_string(i));
        FileTemp.append(FileExtension);

        bool FileCheck = FileExistenceCheck(FileTemp.data());

        if (!FileCheck)
            return ERROR_IMAGEFILENOTEXIST;


        vectorImages.push_back(imread(FileTemp));   

}

cog->VariableTransfer(vectorImages);
```

And here is the interface class in the DLL:

```
class COGInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~COGInterface() {};

public:
    virtual int ImageLoader(Mat &image) = NULL;
    virtual int VariableTransfer(vector<cv::Mat> vimage) = NULL;
};

   // And this is the hidden class in the same DLL:

class COGDLL : public COGInterface {

 public:
    COGDLL() {}
    ~COGDLL() {}

    void destroy() {delete this;}

        public:
            vector<string> strReport;
            vector<cv::Mat> vectorImages;

            Mat OriginalImage;
            Mat GrayImage;
            Mat RoIImage;
            Mat tPatternImage;
            Mat bPatternImage;

            int NumberofFiles;

            int ImageLoader(Mat &image);
            int MainProcess(Mat &image);
            int Preprocess(Mat &image);

            int VariableTransfer(vector<cv::Mat> vimage);
        };

        int COGDLL::ImageLoader(Mat &image)
        {


            imshow("test", image);
            waitKey(0);

            return 0;
        }


        int COGDLL::VariableTransfer(vector<Mat> loasters)
        {
            vectorImages.swap(loasters);

            imshow("Testers", vectorImages[0]);

            waitKey(0);

            return 0;
        }

        extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) COGInterface* __cdecl CreateCOGInterfaceObject()
        {
            return new COGDLL;
        }
```

Before I begin the transfer the vector, I checked the images are all OK in the vector but after that, it is completely changed and the vector looks like it doesn't have the same images at all.

Left: Before, right: after the transfer.

[image: "Before"]
[image: "After"]

How can I make the class receive the same vector from the main app?
Thanks!

Comment: If you did any change in `int MainProcess(Mat &image)` or `int Preprocess(Mat &image)`, make sure you did it on its copy, e.g. `image.clone()` if you don't want to change the original `image`.

Comment: There is no implementation in those functions. I had just transferred the vector from the main to the class in the DLL. After the transfer, it looks like it was lost.